# Python 3 | Unicode Error | Requests and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still in the process of learning Python 3 and I am trying to make a program that uses Requests and BeautifulSoup to accomplish this.
I'm new to both this modules.

I'm having this error relating to Unicode because I'm trying to save the code on a file before analysing it.

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Gonçalo\Desktop\Coding\Python\Web Crawler\Image Retriver.py", line 25, in <module>
    saveFile.write(soup)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200e' in position 145890: character maps to <undefined>
```

Code:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import os


url = "https://www.google.pt/search?q=hello"
req = requests.get(url)
resp = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp,"html.parser")
soup = soup.prettify()


dir_list = os.listdir()
if "Image Retriever Files" not in dir_list:
        os.makedir("Image Retriever Files")
curDir = os.curdir
filename = curDir+"/Image Retriever Files/Search Results.html"
saveFile = open(filename,"w")
saveFile.write(soup)
saveFile.close()
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This can get you closer, but you will have others issues, you should wrap this in a try/except block and extend that if with an else, because you didnt state what you wanted it to do if the folder existed(you will get an error if it exist).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

url = "https://www.google.pt/search?q=hello"
req = requests.get(url)
resp = req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, "html.parser")
soup = soup.prettify()

dir_list = os.getcwd()
if "imageFile" not in dir_list:
    os.mkdir("imageFile")
curDir = os.curdir
filename = curDir + "/imageFile/SearchResults.html"
saveFile = open(filename, "wb")
saveFile.write('files')
saveFile.close()
```

I hope this sets you on the right path. If it did hit the check box, and if not I am here to help.
Regards,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923375/remove-all-characters-from-a-string-whos-ordinals-are-out-of-range).  Your problem is a feature of unicode.  In the beginning there was ASCII and 128 characters was all anyone ever needed.

And then some bright people saw that 8 bits for a character would give them 256 characters, and thus was born codepages where different systems would use characters 128-256 for symbols and letters for other languages.  And all was good until people wanted to represent more than one language in a file, or heaven forbid, a language with more than 256 symbols.

And then some other bright people said use more bits!  But how many 16?, 32? But what if I don't want my file size to double or quadruple? And more smart people said "Simple we'll use an encoding" and thus was born utf-8 and ISO 8859-1 and their ilk.  And more smart people said lets give every character and symbol their one true value and number, thus was born unicode.

'\u200e' is a unicode character indicating text that displays left to right.  It has no keyboard equivalent.
saveFile = open(filename,"w") is trying to write to a standard text file and it assumes everycharacter can be written with an 8-bit value.  'u200e' has a decimal value of 8,206.  To solve your problem you need to choose an encoding like utf-8 explicitly, so that yours strings can be written to a file in a readable manner.  Just changing the file type to saveFile = open(filename, "wb") just kicks the can down the road to when you try and read the file.

Check out this article from Joel Spolsky on [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)