# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200f' with python script

Tags: python, encoding

I am using python to copy part of a field and copy it to another field (in a table). It was working before but now I am getting this UnicodeEncodeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "O:\Projects\NetworkAnalyst\Scripts\python\FiretrailsNameToRoadName.py", line 73, in <module>
    elif len(str(row[0]).split()) == 1:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u200f' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I find out what character I am having problem with? And would it be the only way to fix it (remove that character?)

Here is the the part of the script where I get the error:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(input_fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        counter = counter + 1
        print counter
        #if NULL, paste Unnamed Firetrail
        if (row[0] is None):
            roadNameBase = "Unnamed"
            roadNameType = "Firetrail"
            row[1] = roadNameBase
            row[2] = roadNameType
          #  cursor.updateRow(row)
        #if name is one word, copy over to roadbasename
        elif len(str(row[0]).split()) == 1:
            roadNameBase = row[0]
            roadNameType = "Firetrail"
            row[1] = roadNameBase
            row[2] = roadNameType
```

Answer (score 0):

tldr: You can delete the character and hope there are no others lurking.  But you really need to understand where that character and its ilk came from.  Was it corrupted data, bad input, bad conversion?

## 1: You should really try and use python 3.  Its time.

## 2:This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923375/remove-all-characters-from-a-string-whos-ordinals-are-out-of-range).

Your problem is a feature of unicode.  In the beginning there was ASCII and 128 characters was all anyone ever needed.

And then some bright people saw that 8 bits for a character would give them 256 characters, and thus was born codepages where different systems would use characters 128-256 for symbols and letters for other languages.  And all was good until people wanted to represent more than one language in a file, or heaven forbid, a language with more than 256 symbols.

And then some other bright people said use more bits!  But how many 16?, 32? But what if I don't want my file size to double or quadruple? And more smart people said "Simple we'll use an encoding" and thus was born utf-8 and ISO 8859-1 and their ilk.  And more smart people said lets give every character and symbol their one true value and number, thus was born unicode.

'\u200f' is a unicode character indicating text that displays right to left.  It has no keyboard equivalent.
str(row[0]) is trying to convert your data to a standard ascii string and it assumes every character can be written with an 8-bit value.  'u200f' has a decimal value of 8,207.  To solve your problem you need to choose an encoding like utf-8 explicitly, so that yours strings can be converted in a readable manner.  Python 3 gives you unicode strings by default. Just saying.

Your database is accepting unicode, so you need to understand why before you start deleting offending characters

Check out this article from Joel Spolsky on [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Hi WombatPM.Thanks for your reply. I am using 2.7 because it is embedded in the program that I am running. I couldn't really see the character in the field. The data is an input from users. Even if I delete it now, it might be something else next time. I probably should think how to restrict user input, once I fully understand what you are saying.. I am new to programming. I tried to use this
decRow0 = unicode(str(row[0]), errors = 'ignore') but still got the same error. I think I am missing something in my understanding...

Comment: Is the program responsible for getting this data or is it another source

Comment: The data is entered by user in another software which writes it to a data fire (So most likely user error, something accidentally pressed on keyboard). The field is a text field and anything can be typed.